# Struts 2 select tag and css error class attribute not working

Tags: java, validation, jsp, struts2, bean-validation

I'm using struts 2.5.27 with the Bean Validation plugin. The `cssErrorClass` attribute on the select tag is not rendering if there is a validation error.

Validation is working, however as I get the error message with `<s:fielderror/>`. So, validation is working, but the aim of this code is to do away with error messages and rather highlight the dropdown box in red.

Here's the JSP:

```xml
<s:select label="person.branch" cssErrorClass="errDropdownField"
headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Branch"
list="viewService.branches" listKey="id" listValue="branchName"
name="person.branch.id"
/>
```

And the Person Entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(Person.class.getName());
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String lastname;
    private String firstname;
    private TitleType title;
    private String homePhone;
    @NotBlank(message="workphone.required")
    private String workPhone;
    private String cell;
    @Size(min=1, message="email.required")
    @Email(message="email.format")
    private String emailAddress;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private Date created;
    private Date updated;
    private Date consentDate;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 20)
    private GenderType genderType;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 20)
    private TitleType titleType;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 20)
    private RaceType race;
    @Valid
    @ManyToOne
    private Branch branch;
    ...
```

Notice the Branch field above.

And the Branch Entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Branch implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @NotEmpty
    private String branchName;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 20)
    private RegionType region;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Country country;

    @AssertTrue(message = "branch.required")
    public boolean isValid() {
        return id == null || id != null && id >= 0;
    }
```

Now, for the record, this JSP **is** working. The input field is rendering with a red border showing the field as required:

```xml
<s:textfield key="person.emailAddress" size="40" maxlength="150" cssErrorClass="errField" />
```

Here is the HTML rendered, you can see the class attribute is missing:

```
<select name="person.branch.id" id="savePerson_person_branch_id">
    <option value="-1"
    selected="selected"
    >Select Branch</option>
    <option value="4">Gauteng</option>
    <option value="19">National</option>
    <option value="23">Cape</option>
    <option value="104">Africa</option>
    <option value="105">International</option>
    <option value="106">KwaZulu Natal</option>
    <option value="1310">Unknown</option>
    <option value="14456">test</option>


</select>
```

Could the error be with the select tag or am I somehow not using validation correctly or something else?

Comment: Please include the rendered HTML (and is this a regression, e.g., did it used to work w/ a previous version of S2?) The UI tags have a generic set of properties, but since they don't all work the same way, it may just be that the select tag styling is incorrect, or that since it's a Very Different Tag than a text tag it cannot work the exact same way.

Comment: I have added the rendered HTML above. This is new code, I never added it in a previous version. It is working with <s:text ...> and <s:checkboxlist ...>

Comment: I'd have to look at the template for the tag, which I can't do at the moment, but will try to remember to later. I suspect that it's either not used in the select tag, or there was a regression.

Comment: According to the struts 2 doc it is being used. Must have been a regression? Google searches are not yielding much which made me think it was might fault. Validation or something.

Comment: Would need to see the set of field errors, the theme you're using, and the CSS to start tracking it down. AFAICT the select tag template itself currently renders the `cssErrorClass` if there are errors present (see [select tag template source](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/26e1535b589c10a80b1d9f138d5b251931a512f7/core/src/main/resources/template/simple/select.ftl#L36))

Comment: I must confess I haven't looked at these templates before. I can find cssClass but not cssErrorClass. Would it inherit from another template?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; the select tag includes the [css template](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/26e1535b589c10a80b1d9f138d5b251931a512f7/core/src/main/resources/template/simple/css.ftl) which (eventually) renders either the `cssClass`, `cssErrorClass`, or both, depending on conditions.

Comment: Doesn't cssErrorClass get rendered in the template as an HTML class attribute when there's a validation error? The same as cssClass. At least, it should be.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I said; if you look in the template I linked to you’ll see the logic used.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Strangely enough the select boxes /dropdowns that use enums as list values are working.

Comment: That's a curious thing. So the validation message is there but the style isn't?